# How can I insert variable into SPARQL query?

Tags: python, sparql, rdflib

I use the [rdflib](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library. I need to insert a variable into a SPARQL query.
I do this:

```
    q = prepareUpdate("""INSERT DATA { <r> a <owl:Ontology> }""")
    g.update(q, initBindings={'r': uri})
    uri = 'http://www.example.org/ontologies/example/example.owl'
    g - object class Graph()
```

Output result: `<r:> a <owl:Ontology>` .

Required result: `<http://www.example.org/ontologies/example/example.owl> a <owl:Ontology>` .

Comment: the correct way via rdflib is to write it as a common SPARQL variable and not as a relative URI which you did via wrapping it in angle brackets (those denote a URI in SPARQL): `INSERT DATA { ?r a <owl:Ontology> }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
q = prepareUpdate("""INSERT DATA { <%s> a <owl:Ontology> }""" % uri)
g.update(q)
```